# Performance Impact of many Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuejs2

we are using Laravel with Vue.js but during the last year the code got a bit messy. We are now beginning to re-write most of it and are discussing how to best go about it.

We are not making use of a SPA so the routes are defined in Laravel. Since there has been some copy / paste we now want to write everything within Vue.js modules and put all of them within one JS file. It works now as we only have around 10 components so far, but considering a whole rewrite we will probably end up with 100 components or more.

The question is: 
If e.g. 100 components are packed within one JS File, does Vue.js need to execute the code of all of them, even if that page only uses e.g. 10 of them, or is only the code executed of those components that are actually used?

If performance wise this is a bad choice, is there another alternative to having every component in one big file (while still maintaining Laravel routes)?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You might want to read more about code splitting https://sebastiandedeyne.com/code-splitting-with-laravel-mix

Comment: You need to split your code and start using dynamic-imports. You can asynchronously load based on many criteria, I suggest reading this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Thank you for that link. But if I split the JS in multiple files I need to track which components are in which filenames and then dynamically load them from PHP. That is definitely way more work than just putting all components within one file. That's also the reason why I am asking how much of a performance issue it is to put all components in one file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference per se, of having 100 or 10 components in the same file.

The difference is that you're requesting the user's browser to load a 100 components instead of 10.

Code splitting the file works great if you're using an SPA, but if you want to use Vue in-page, it's, obviously, not ideal.

What you could do, however, is have all components be loaded as one file, and the vue instances that use them across multiple pages reference them. That way when you go from page to page you're not requiring the user to load new sets.

If you want to have actual performance improvement, you can optimize the rendering as much as possible, as there you will find the most noticeable gains. One way is to convert components to functional components, which can make an impact if you have lots of components re-rendering frequently, but it doesn't seem like that's the case.